# Binding width c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

How can I bind width in C#?

In XAML it would be

```
Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=img}"
```

I need to bind it in C# to update the width

Comment: MSDN: [How to: Create a Binding in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx)

Comment: Are you using MVVM?  It's all quite straight-forward in that pattern.  Otherwise you can bind it to whatever is providing the data context.

Comment: Why do you want  to do that in procedural code?? That's what XAML is for.

Comment: I need to do it to get a rotatetransform/layouttransform to work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Binding mybinding = new Binding();
mybinding.Path.Path = "ActualWidth";
mybinding.ElementName = "img"
Mytarget.SetBinding(MYTARGET.WidthProperty, mybinding);
```

`MYTARGET` is class and `Mytarget` is object name.

Comment: It says cannot implicitly convert type string to system.windows.propertypath and System.Windows.FrameworkElement.WidthProperty' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: path.path what is it?

Comment: Thanks, figured it out

Answer (score 0):

I made it work like this

```
            Binding b = new Binding();
            b.Source = img;
            b.Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth");
            ui.SetBinding(Grid.WidthProperty, b);
```

if anyone is interested, setting it as Path.Path doesn't work as intended, but this does.